# Elasticsearch tags aggregation with specific keys

Tags: elasticsearch

I have an array field with tags and fixed list of 10 most popular tags (I got it from previous terms aggregations call).

Can I determine document counts for current search exactly with this keys (tags from my array)? Like terms aggregation, but for specific keys only.

Thanks!

Comment: could you post your current query? what kind of output you are expecting?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at [filtering terms aggregations](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html#_filtering_values_2), especially the `include` parameter. It would be easier to show you if you provided a specific example of your problem, but here is the example from the docs that should help you figure out how to solve your problem:

```
{
    "aggs" : {
        "JapaneseCars" : {
             "terms" : {
                 "field" : "make",
                 "include" : ["mazda", "honda"]
             }
         },
        "ActiveCarManufacturers" : {
             "terms" : {
                 "field" : "make",
                 "exclude" : ["rover", "jensen"]
             }
         }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use **include** or **exclude** keywords inside **aggregations** to filter your keys.

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "my_agg": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "agg_field",
        "include": [key1,key2,key3]
      }
    }
  }
}
```